# how to configure /etc/udev/rules.d/ syntax?

Tags: udev

I am confused about how to configure udev rules for /dev/xxx.

Q1: I can't find where defined /dev/random?

```
#ll /dev/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 Aug  4 17:57 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Aug  4 17:57 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1,   7 Aug  4 17:57 full
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 229 Aug  4 17:57 fuse
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       0 Aug  4 17:57 hugepages
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Aug  4 17:57 initctl -> /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root       0 Aug  4 17:57 log
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root      40 Aug  4 17:57 mqueue
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1,   3 Aug  4 17:57 null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Aug  4 17:57 ptmx -> pts/ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       0 Aug  4 17:57 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1,   8 Aug  4 17:57 random
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root      40 Aug  4 17:57 shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Aug  4 17:57 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Aug  4 17:57 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Aug  4 17:57 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  5,   0 Aug  4 17:57 tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1,   9 Aug  4 17:57 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  1,   5 Aug  4 17:57 zero][1]


[root@xxxxx /]
#cat /lib/udev/rules.d/*  |  grep mqueue

[root@xxxxx /]
#cat /lib/udev/rules.d/*  |  grep random
# Rule for prandom character device node permissions
KERNEL=="prandom", MODE="0644"

[root@xxxxxx /]
#cat /etc/udev/rules.d/* | grep random
```

also can not find defualt rule

```
#cat /lib/udev/rules.d/* | grep "KERNEL==\"*\""
KERNEL=="device-mapper", NAME="mapper/control"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="bridge", RUN+="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/proc/sys/net/bridge"
KERNEL=="prandom", MODE="0644"
SUBSYSTEM=="virtio-ports", KERNEL=="vport*", ATTR{name}=="?*", SYMLINK+="virtio-ports/$attr{name}"
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", KERNEL=="rtc0", SYMLINK+="rtc", OPTIONS+="link_priority=-100"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ptmx", GROUP="tty", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="tty", GROUP="tty", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="tty[0-9]*", GROUP="tty", MODE="0620"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="sclp_line[0-9]*", GROUP="tty", MODE="0620"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttysclp[0-9]*", GROUP="tty", MODE="0620"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="3270/tty[0-9]*", GROUP="tty", MODE="0620"
SUBSYSTEM=="vc", KERNEL=="vcs*|vcsa*", GROUP="tty"
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*[0-9]|pppox[0-9]*|ircomm[0-9]*|noz[0-9]*|rfcomm[0-9]*", GROUP="dialout"
SUBSYSTEM=="mem", KERNEL=="mem|kmem|port", GROUP="kmem", MODE="0640"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="js[0-9]*", MODE="0664"
SUBSYSTEM=="misc", KERNEL=="agpgart", GROUP="video"
KERNEL=="parport[0-9]*", GROUP="lp"
SUBSYSTEM=="printer", KERNEL=="lp*", GROUP="lp"
KERNEL=="lp[0-9]*", GROUP="lp"
KERNEL=="irlpt[0-9]*", GROUP="lp"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", GROUP="cdrom"
KERNEL=="sch[0-9]*", GROUP="cdrom"
KERNEL=="pktcdvd[0-9]*", GROUP="cdrom"
KERNEL=="pktcdvd", GROUP="cdrom"
KERNEL=="qft[0-9]*|nqft[0-9]*|zqft[0-9]*|nzqft[0-9]*|rawqft[0-9]*|nrawqft[0-9]*", GROUP="disk"
KERNEL=="loop-control", GROUP="disk", OPTIONS+="static_node=loop-control"
KERNEL=="btrfs-control", GROUP="disk"
KERNEL=="rawctl", GROUP="disk"
SUBSYSTEM=="raw", KERNEL=="raw[0-9]*", GROUP="disk"
SUBSYSTEM=="aoe", KERNEL=="err", MODE="0440"
KERNEL=="rfkill", MODE="0664"
KERNEL=="tun", MODE="0666", OPTIONS+="static_node=net/tun"
KERNEL=="fuse", MODE="0666", OPTIONS+="static_node=fuse"
KERNEL=="loop*|ram*", GOTO="log_end"
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", ENV{ID_CDROM}="1"
KERNEL=="sr0", SYMLINK+="cdrom", OPTIONS+="link_priority=-100"
KERNEL=="mouse*|js*", ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="|00", SYMLINK+="input/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
KERNEL=="mouse*|js*", ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}!="00", SYMLINK+="input/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$attr{bInterfaceNumber}-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="|00", SYMLINK+="input/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-event-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
KERNEL=="event*", ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="?*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}!="00", SYMLINK+="input/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$attr{bInterfaceNumber}-event-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", KERNEL=="event*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="?*", \
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="mouse*|js*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", SYMLINK+="input/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="event*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="?*", SYMLINK+="input/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-event-$env{.INPUT_CLASS}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb|platform", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="event*", ENV{.INPUT_CLASS}=="", \
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="block", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}=="0", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}="2000"
KERNEL=="fd*|mtd*|nbd*|gnbd*|btibm*|dm-*|md*|zram*|mmcblk[0-9]*rpmb", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"
KERNEL=="vd*[!0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="vd*[0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{type}=="5", ATTRS{scsi_level}=="[6-9]*", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", ATTR{removable}=="0", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", IMPORT{program}="scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d $devnode", ENV{ID_BUS}="scsi"
KERNEL=="cciss*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", IMPORT{program}="scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d $devnode", ENV{ID_BUS}="cciss"
KERNEL=="sd*|sr*|cciss*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="sd*|cciss*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ieee1394-$attr{ieee1394_id}"
KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ieee1394-$attr{ieee1394_id}-part%n"
KERNEL=="mmcblk[0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="mmc", ATTRS{name}=="?*", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_NAME}="$attr{name}", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/mmc-$env{ID_NAME}_$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="mmcblk[0-9]p[0-9]", ENV{ID_NAME}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/mmc-$env{ID_NAME}_$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
KERNEL=="mspblk[0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="memstick", ATTRS{name}=="?*", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_NAME}="$attr{name}", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/memstick-$env{ID_NAME}_$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="mspblk[0-9]p[0-9]", ENV{ID_NAME}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/memstick-$env{ID_NAME}_$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
KERNEL=="sr*", ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}!="?*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT_DATA}=="?*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_LAST_OFFSET}=="?*", \
KERNEL=="sr*", ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}!="?*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT_DATA}=="?*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_LAST_OFFSET}=="", \
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{ieee1394_id}", ENV{ID_BUS}="ieee1394"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", KERNELS=="[0-9]*:*[0-9]", ENV{.BSG_DEV}="$root/bsg/$id"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", IMPORT{program}="scsi_id --whitelisted --export --device=$env{.BSG_DEV}", ENV{ID_BUS}="scsi"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]",  ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="tape/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="nst*[0-9]", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="tape/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-nst"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
KERNEL=="st*[0-9]", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="tape/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}"
KERNEL=="nst*[0-9]", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="tape/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-nst"
KERNEL=="video*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-video-index$attr{index}"
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="video*|vbi*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-video-index$attr{index}"
ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="audio*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-audio-index$attr{index}"
#   ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sda", RUN+="/usr/bin/raw /dev/raw/raw1 %N"
KERNEL=="dm-*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="linux_raid_member", \
KERNEL=="md*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="linux_raid_member", \
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="md[0-9]*p[0-9]*", GOTO="lvm_scan"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", SUBSYSTEMS=="acpi", TAG+="power-switch"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", KERNELS=="thinkpad_acpi", TAG+="power-switch"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="twl4030_pwrbutton", TAG+="power-switch"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="tps65217_pwr_but", TAG+="power-switch"
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card*|renderD*", TAG+="uaccess"
SUBSYSTEM=="misc", KERNEL=="kvm", TAG+="uaccess"
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", KERNEL=="card*", TAG+="seat"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="input*", TAG+="seat"
SUBSYSTEM=="graphics", KERNEL=="fb[0-9]*", TAG+="seat", TAG+="master-of-seat"
KERNEL=="mtd*ro", IMPORT{program}="mtd_probe $devnode"
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="controlC*", ATTR{../uevent}="change"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="parport_pc", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load ppdev"
KERNEL=="mtd*ro", ENV{MTD_FTL}=="smartmedia", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load sm_ftl"
KERNEL=="regulatory*", ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", RUN+="/sbin/crda"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="vtconsole", KERNEL=="vtcon*", RUN+="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup"
KERNEL=="controlD[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", MODE="0600"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="cxgb*", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="ib_*", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="mlx*", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="iw_*", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="be2net", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="enic", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="rdma.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="infiniband", KERNEL=="*", ACTION=="add", TEST!="/usr/sbin/rdma-ndd", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'sleep 1; echo -n `hostname -s` %k > /sys/class/infiniband/%k/node_desc'"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="tty[a-zA-Z]*|hvc*|xvc*|hvsi*|ttysclp*|sclp_line*|3270/tty[0-9]*", TAG+="systemd"
KERNEL=="vport*", TAG+="systemd"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", KERNEL=="md*", TEST!="md/array_state", ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="0"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", KERNEL=="md*", ATTR{md/array_state}=="|clear|inactive", ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="0"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="loop[0-9]*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", TEST!="loop/backing_file", ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="nbd*", ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="0"
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", KERNEL=="card*", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="sound.target"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="lp*", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="printer.target"
SUBSYSTEM=="leds", KERNEL=="*kbd_backlight", TAG+="systemd", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="systemd-backlight@leds:$name.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="fuse", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="configfs", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="sys-kernel-config.mount"
```

Q2: If I add this rule , I hope /dev/random access become 0777 , but badly,after reboot, I find this configure is invalid. /dev/random access is still 0666, Is this configure wrong ?

this is just a example I want to verify syntax， This example may not be appropriate， I am not really want to modify /dev/random access from 0666 to 0777

```
[root@xxxxxx /]
#cat  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-muahao.rules
KERNEL=="random",  GROUP="root", MODE="0777", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Answer (score 0):

A1:
Not all devices in `/dev/` originate from udev.

As an example `/dev/random` is a character device backed up by Linux kernel (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt for details). The actual `mknod` entry into devtmpfs is populated by your chosen distro's initial ramdisk.

A2: See A1. As the device is never handled by udev, the rule would not apply.